# Job enter exit status right after submited

Tags: queue, pbs, qsub, torque

I am using PBS queue, there was a queue that when I submit a job, it immediately enter the exit status, and there is no output/error file available (Like, no do.sh.exxxxxxxxx and do.sh.oxxxxxxx)

When I use python to submit a sequence of job, some of the job will go into R state for several second, and then enter exit state. Those who had entered R states will have output/error files

the error files shows

`tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/9282194.redwood.speech.cs.cmu.edu.SC: Command not found.`

The queue itself should be fine, cause other people are submitting jobs on it happily, but I just can't submit even a job. The script I use is also useable on other machine, so I believe the script should be fine. I just don't know why there is a specific machine I can't submit.

Thank you for reading this post, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The last line of the output suggests that the job script was not copied correctly onto the work node. The node might be out of disk space or accounts have not been set up yet, or the shell requested in the script is not available on the work node. Only the systems' admins could know what's happening.

Comment: The tput thing is caused by something in your profile. It is likely a CSH/TCSH profile. Which shells are available on the system? And which shell is requested in your job script? A script working on one machine does not guarantee it is correct for another system.